# Using Wireshark to extract payload from captured packets to in CSV file

Tags: csv, networking, simulation, wireshark

I run Wireshark to capture packets generated from my simulation. I use File > Export Packet Dissection > As CSV... to extract the captured packets into CSV file in order to do some machine learning. The following is an example of I got:

```
No.| Time|  Source| Destination|    Protocol|   Length| Info|
1   0.45    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 76  40656  >  6633 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=43690 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=454250 TSecr=0 WS=512
```

My question is: How do I get the payload itself from the packet?

Comment: The payload of the packet is the TCP segment. CSV is a text file but the TCP segment header is going to be binary, and it is likely that the segment payload is binary, also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting the payload can be difficult,  depends on link encryption. In case the link is unencrypted It's possible in some cases and CSV is one of them. Please follow this [link](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html).  Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: Thank you for answering ... I tried the link but I still cannot extract the payload. Note that the payload in my case is unencrypted. Can you find another way ? THANK YOU

Comment: Can you share the pcap file so I can try to assist?

Comment: Did you follow **5.7.8. The "Export Objects" dialog box**. It supposed to be pretty straight forward.